# Range query over strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table in which a column represents a particular timestamp in this format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" The type of the column is **string**

What if i wanted to select those rows between two dates ("yyyy-MM-dd")? Is it possible without changing the column type to datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from mytable
where ts between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-15 z'
```

should work because 'z' is "greater" than any digit. But it would be "cleaner" to use

```
where ts between '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000' and '2016-10-15 23:59:59.999'
```

**Update:**

In general, if you (for example) want to select any timestamp in the date range from `2016-10-01` to `2016-10-15`, your `start_str` and `end_str` must meet the following rules:

```
'2016-09-30 23:59:59.999' <  start_str <= '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000'
'2016-10-15 23:59:59.999' <= end_str   <  '2016-10-16 00:00:00.000'
```

Some possible values for `start_str`:

```
'2016-10-01'
'2016-10-01 00:00:00'
'2016-10-01 00:00:00.000'
'2016-09-30 24'
'2016-09-30 3'
```

Some possible values for `end_str`:

```
'2016-10-15 23:59:59.999'
'2016-10-15 23:59:59.999999'
'2016-10-15 24'
'2016-10-15 3'
'2016-10-15 a'
'2016-10-15 z'
'2016-10-16'
```

To answer your question in the comment: You can pass a string representation of the start date, but you can't do it with the end date. In terms of string comparison `2016-10-15` is lesser than `2016-10-15 23:59:59.999` and thus it would break the rule `'2016-10-15 23:59:59.999' <= end_str` and you would filter out any timestamp from that day.

Additionaly - if you use one of the follwing conditions

```
where ts between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-15 23:59:59.999999'

where ts between '2016-10-01 00:00:00' and '2016-10-15 23:59:59.999999'
```

you can change the data type to `TIMESTAMP(3)` or `TIMESTAMP(6)` later and yor query will still work.

If your date range comes from some other table, you would need a concatenation

```
select *
from timestamps t
join dateranges r
  on t.ts between r.start_date and concat(r.end_date, '23:59:59.999999')
where r.some_column = 'some_value'
```

Comment: so i've just to pass string dates to my query?

Comment: @lorisstefano - Hope the update will unswer your question. Also see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use str_to_date   for the format  yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

```
select * from my_table  
where   str_to_date(my_column, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.$f') 
            between str_to_date('01-01-2016 00:00:00' , '%d-%m-%Y HH:mm:ss') 
                 and str_to_date('31-12-2016 23:59:59' , '%d-%m-%Y HH:mm:ss') ;
```

Comment: If there's an index on the column, this will be unable to use it. And parsing dates is likely to be much slower than just doing string comparisons.

Comment: But a bigger problem is that this will miss all the times on last day. Your end time is `2016-12-31 00:00:00`, so `2016-12-31 15:00:00` won't be included.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
select *
from tableName
where date between 'yyyy-MM-dd' and 'yyyy-MM-dd';
```

And if you want to search result inclusive date defined you should add `1` in `to` date (ending date).

Answer (score 0):

This is what i usually use for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns:

```
select *
from mytable
where ts >= '2016-10-01'
  and ts <  '2016-10-15' + interval 1 day
```

This will also work with string columns, aslong as you store the timestamps in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where columnname between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-15 z'
```

Comment: Is the "z" intended or a typing mistake ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.